# How to get Google Drive location by Google Docs ID or URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, directory, google-drive-api

I'm currently trying (but unfortunately haven't got a clue) to

- get the folder name (last folder not the parent ones)
- of the given Google Doc (ID or URL)
- write it into a specific Column called "Folder"
- of a specific Worksheet (ID)

This should loop until the last row/ID is fetched.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[This is the example file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdWZe.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Get path back to My Drive from file Id**

Try this:

```
function getFilePathFromId(id) {
  var id=id||"Put a default id in here for debugging pick one that is buried into the folders";
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  var pA=[];
  pA.push(file.getName());
  var folder=file.getParents();
  do{
    var f=folder.next();
    pA.push(f.getName());
    folder=f.getParents()
  }while(folder.hasNext())
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(pA.reverse().join(' / ')), 'Path for ' + file.getName());
}
```

**Get Path back to My Drive with Id or Url**

```
function getFilePathFromId(id) {
  var id=id||"**********id or url***********";
  var s=id.slice(0,6);
  if(s!='https:') {
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  }else{
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id.slice(id.indexOf('/d/')+3,id.indexOf('/edit')));
  }
  var pA=[];
  pA.push(file.getName());
  var folder=file.getParents();
  do{
    var f=folder.next();
    pA.push(f.getName());
    folder=f.getParents()
  }while(folder.hasNext())
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(pA.reverse().join(' / ')), 'Path for: ' + file.getName());
}
```